# Residues of Complex Functions

Tags: complex-analysis, contour-integration, residue-calculus

I need to find the residues of $f$ at the isolated singular points, namely $z=1,z=0$.

Where $f(z)=\dfrac{2z+1}{z(z+1)}$.

I already have that the residue at $z=0$ is $1$, and I know I need to do some slight of hand to get res at $z=1$.

I tried, $f(z)=\dfrac{2z+1}{z(z+1)} = (\dfrac{2z+1}{z})(\dfrac{1}{2+(z-1)}) = (2+d\dfrac{1}{z})*\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(-1)^n\dfrac{(z-1)^n}{2^{n+1}}$, but we never get a $\dfrac{1}{z-1}$ term, so can we conclude that the coefficient of $\dfrac{1}{z-1} = res  =0?$

I would need this to conclude that, $\int_C f(z) dz = 2i\pi(1+0)=2i\pi$. Where C is the circle of radius 2.

Yes, I know I can use partial fractions to do this, but our professor wants us to use the Residue Theorem to evaluate the integral.

Comment: The second pole is at $\;z=-1\;$ , not at $\;z=1\;$ .

Comment: Omg, that's where I made the mistake then. Yes, so the res at z=-1 is 1.

Comment: Indeed so, @3.1416

Comment: So this integral that I mentioned in the problem show be $4i\pi$ instead of $2i\pi$ correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint:

$$\frac{2z+1}{z(z+1)}=\frac1z+\frac1{z+1}=-\frac1{1-(z+1)}+\frac1{z+1}=$$

$$-1-(z+1)-(z+1)^2-\ldots+\frac1{z+1}\;\;\implies\;\ldots$$

Comment: Thanks, I got it. $(2-\frac{1}{z+1})(-1-(z+1)-(z+1)^2-...)$ and we have, $\frac{-1}{z+1}*-1 = \frac{1}{z+1}$

Comment: Well, but if you have what I wrote (which is, imo, shorter and simpler), then it is straightforward what the coefficient of $\;(z+1)^{-1}\;$ is in the Laurent Expansion...

Answer (score 1):

Given $$f(z)=g(z)/(z-z_0)$$ where $f(z)$ is analytic at $z_0$ the residue of $g(z)$ at $z_0$ is simply $g(z_0)$. So the residue at $z=-1$ is given by $\frac{2z+1}{z}$ evaluated at $z=-1$ which gives a value of $1$.

As an extension of this, you may be interested in the [Cauchy Integral Formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%27s_integral_formula).

Comment: So this integral that I mentioned in the problem show be $4i\pi$ instead of $2i\pi$ correct?

Comment: Yep! As the integral is $2(2\pi i)$.